# Humanizing django-tables2 output?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

Here's a hack I'm currently using:

```
class ProductMaxIPPortEldCountMonthlyTable(tables.Table):                      
    ip_count = tables.TemplateColumn('{% load humanize %}{{ record.ip_count|intcomma }} ')
```

I'm using `django.contrib.humanize`. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import the [`intcomma`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma) template filter, and define a [custom render method](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/custom-rendering.html#table-render-foo-methods) for the column that uses it.

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma

class ProductMaxIPPortEldCountMonthlyTable(tables.Table):                      
    ip_count = tables.Column()

    def render_ip_count(self, value):
        return intcomma(value)
```